# If Ubuntu is installed along-side of Windows, can it be deleted later?

Tags: dual-boot, uninstall

If Ubuntu is installed along-side of Windows, can it be uninstalled later?

Comment: Yes, definitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes. But it is not like the process of uninstalling a software. You have to format the partition on which Ubuntu resides and then update the mbr with Windows boot code. See this question details about uninstalling Ubuntu.

- [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/q/133533/61218)